# Derive the identity elements of lcm and gcd

Tags: arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

> Find the identity element of the binary operations $*,*'$ on $\mathbb{N}$ given by $a*b = lcm(a,b)$ and $a*'b = \gcd(a,b)$, where $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3...\}$

I know the identity element for lcm is $1$ and there is none for gcd in $\mathbb{N}$. But, how do I prove it mathematically ?

**My Attempt**

$a*e=a=e*a$

From the fundamental theorem of arithmetic,
$$
a=\prod_ip_i^{a_i}\quad,e=\prod_ip_i^{e_i}\\
lcm(a,b)=\prod_ip_i^{\max(a_i,b_i)}\quad ,\gcd(a,b)=\prod_ip_i^{\min(a_i,b_i)}
$$
For $*:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$
$$
a*e=a\implies lcm(a,e)=\prod_ip_i^{\max(a_i,e_i)}=\prod_ip_i^{a_i}=a\\
\implies \max(a_i,e_i)=a_i\implies e_i\leq a_i \text{ for all }a_i\\
\implies e_i=0\implies \color{red}{e=1}
$$
For $*':\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$
$$
a*'e=a\implies \gcd(a,e)=\prod_ip_i^{\min(a_i,e_i)}=\prod_ip_i^{a_i}=a\\
\implies \min(a_i,e_i)=a_i\implies e_i\geq a_i\text{ for all }a_i\\
\implies \text{no }e_i\in\mathbb{N}\text{ satisfies the condition}\implies\color{red}{\text{no identity element for }*'}
$$
Is it the right way to approach the problem ?

Comment: Suppose there were an identity element for $\gcd$, call it $A$.  Then look at the sequence of primes $\{p_i\}$.  We have $\gcd (A,p_i)=p_i\;\forall i$ so...

Comment: Is $0 \in \mathbb{N}?$

Comment: @gammatester nope.

Comment: It would be $0$ if that was allowed. Because everything divides $0$.

Comment: @TonyK yea I can see that. but how can I derive it from the fundamental definition of gcd and lcm ?

Comment: @gammatester even if I iclude $0$, how can I derive it as tried in my attempt ?

Comment: $a$ divides $a$ and $0$. Since $a\ge 0$ it follows that $a = \gcd(a,0)$.

Comment: @gammatester i knw that, its that simple to see. but, how do I derive it from the definition of gcd, ie. $gcd(a,b)=\prod_i p_i^{min(a_i,b_i)}$, where $p_i:i^{th}$ prime number

Comment: Don't use *that* definition.  Use the *basic* definition thatt $\gcd(a,b)$ is the largest number that is a common divisor to $a$ and $b$.  $a|a$ and $a|0$ so $a$ is a common divisor.  and if $m > a > 0$ then $m\not \mid a$.  So... $a$ is the *greatest* common divisor.  By definition.

Comment: that definition is only for natural numbers.  For negative integers and zero.... well, special cases must be made.  And if there are any fraction are irrationals ...well forgetaboutit.

Comment: Using your difinition.  If $\gcd(e,a) = a$ for every $a$ then $p_i^{\min a_i, e_i}= p_i^{e_i}$ and $e_i \ge a_i$ for *EVERY POSSIBLE* $a_i$.  That is not possible.

Comment: .... or let $a = 2$ so $\gcd(e, 2e) = 2e$.  Is that possible for a natural number $e$.  By your def $e = \prod p^{e_i}$ so for $p_1 = 2$ we'd have $\min(e_1, e_1 + 1) = e_1 + 1$.  So $e_1+ 1 \le e_1$ and $1 < 0$ and say wha......

Answer (score 1):

In your approach for $\gcd(a,e)=a$, you get that $\min(a_i,e_i)=a_i$ for all $i$. But keep in mind that $e$ will act as an identity for all elements $a$.

In particular, it should work as identity if we consider $a=e^2$, i.e. we should have $\gcd(e^2,e)=e^2$. But the prime factorization of $e^2$ will of the form $\prod_ip_i^{2e_i}$. So here we have $a_i=2e_i > e_i$. But this violates $\min(2e_i,e_i)=2e_i$. So no such $e$ exists.

**Note:** But as suggested by many others, going through prime factorization approach is an overkill for this problem.

Comment: Quibble.  $2e_i = e_i$ if $e_i= 0$.  So that would mean $e = 1$.  which.... is obvious not an answer....

Answer (score 0):

$a*b = lcm(a,b)$

Prove that if $lcm(a,e) = a$ for all natural $a$ then $e = 1$.

Pf:  $lcm(a,e) = \frac {ae}{\gcd(a,e)}$.

So if $lcm(a,e) =  \frac {ae}{\gcd(a,e)} =a$ for all natural $a$ then

$ae = a*\gcd(a,e)$ for all natural numbers.

So $e = \gcd(a,e)$ for all natural numbers.

So $e$ divides *all* natural numbers.

So $e$ divides $1$.  The only natural number that divides $1$ is $1$.

So $e = 1$.

And indeed $a*1 = lcm(a,1) = a$ for all $a$.

$a *' b = \gcd(a,e)$

So prove find an $e$ so that $\gcd(a,e) = a$ for all $a$ or prove one can't exist.

S'pose there were such an $e$ then $\gcd(a,e) =a$ for all possible $a$.

So all $a$ will divide $e$.  So we must find a number that is divisible by any other number.

Well, that would mean $2e|e$ so there is an integer $k$ so that $e = k*(2e)$ so if $e\ne 0$ then $k = \frac 12$ which is not an integer.  So $e = 0$.

And  .... every number *does* divide $0$ because $a*0 = 0$ for every number.

And $\gcd(a,0) = a$.  Because $a|0$ and $a|a$.  And if $m > a > 0$ then $m\not \mid a$.

But the question now is, was it specified that the identity element must be in $\mathbb N$?

I guess so because otherwize $-1$ would be an identity element for $*$.  SO as $0 \not \in \mathbb N$ I guess we can say there is no natural number that is an identity.